# Setting variables VBA error

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint, vbe

I am getting an error when trying to execute the following subroutine

"Runtime Error: 9, Subscript out of range"

its highlighting the first variable declaration. At first I thought it was due to the wrong datatype but changing and playing around with that had no luck.

I also tried both Cells & Range

```
Public vFolderPath As String
Public vCMFNewPath As String
Public vKBNewPath As String
Public vDPI As Integer

Private Sub SetGlobal()

Dim vGo As String
Dim vTemplateLocation As String
Dim vCMFFilename As String
Dim vKBFilename As String
Dim vDriver As String
Dim vPKG As String

    vDPI = Workbooks("tools.xlsm").Sheets("SETTINGS").Range("B2").Value

    vFolderPath = Workbooks("tools.xlsm").Sheets("SETTINGS").Range("B3").Value & "\"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you running the sub from (within a worksheet or a module)? That can affect variable visibility. Try testing each variable individually to make sure you have spelled them correctly e.g. `MsgBox Workbooks("tools.xlsm").Name`, `MsgBox Workbooks("tools.xlsm").Sheets("SETTINGS").Name` - hopefully that will identify where the problem is.

Comment: Is that the full code? Where's your `End Sub`? For the sake of removing the obvious: you DO have a workbook called `tools.xlsm` open, and that workboko does have a sheet named `SETTINGS`, right?

Comment: The code is just the first lines as OP said that error occurs on first line. I am inclined to agree that the problem lies in the fact that the file and or tab are incorrectly named or do not exist.

Comment: Add these two lines before you set the vDPI variable value and let me know if either of them cause the same error.  `Set wb = Workbooks("tools.xlsm")` and then `Set ws = Workbooks("tools.xlsm").Sheets("Settings")`.

Answer (score 3):

Code works fine, running from a file called Tools.xslm. with a tab called Settings, an integer in cell B2 and a string value in cell B3.

This works when running from a module in Personal xlsb or from within Tools.xlsm. It works even if you do not declare any of the variables.

Comment: thks figured it out im working with versions of the file and somewhere it got renamed to tool.xlsm thks for all the help

Comment: Glad you figured it out, nothing more frustrating than trying to fix things on multiple versions of files!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
Public vFolderPath As String
Public vCMFNewPath As String
Public vKBNewPath As String
Public vDPI As Integer

Private Sub SetGlobal()


    Dim vGo As String
    Dim vTemplateLocation As String
    Dim vCMFFilename As String
    Dim vKBFilename As String
    Dim vDriver As String
    Dim vPKG As String

    Dim wkbSetting As Workbook, shtSetting As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wkbSetting = Workbooks("tools.xlsm")
    On Error GoTo 0

    On Error GoTo err_rout
    If Not wkbSetting Is Nothing Then

        On Error Resume Next
        Set shtSetting = wkbSetting.Sheets("SETTINGS")
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error GoTo err_rout
        If shtSetting Is Nothing Then
            Err.Raise Number:=32, Description:="Sheets Settings not found"
        End If


        vDPI = CInt(shtSetting.Range("B2").Value)
        vFolderPath = shtSetting.Range("B3").Value & "\"

    Else
        Err.Raise Number:=31, Description:="Workbook - tools.xlsm not found"
    End If


Exit Sub
err_rout:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbInformation

End Sub
```